# How to find a simultaneous solution to these equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations

**QUESTION**

$$x^2 + xy + yz + xz = 30$$

$$y^2 + xy + yz + xz = 15$$

$$z^2 + xy + yz + xz = 18$$

I have tried manipulating the expressions, the identity of $(x+y+z)^2$ but to no avail.

Along with the answer, it would be great if you can explain the approach and thought process involved in dealing with such kind of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x+y = a, y+z = b, z + x = c$.
Rewrite the equations in term of $a,b,c$.

---

The approach and thought process is by recognizing the pattern of how the LHS factorizes.

Comment: I believe that would be z+x=c.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: It works to give x=4,y=1,z=2

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say whether $x,y,z$ are real or integer. But let's see what happens if we assume they're integer.

We can eliminate the cross terms $xy + yz + xz$ by subtraction.

$$\begin{align}
x^2-y^2 &= 15\\
x^2-z^2 &= 12\\
z^2-y^2 &= 3\\
\end{align}$$

Now factorizing,

$$z^2-y^2 = (z+y)(z-y) = 3$$
So (if they're positive integers),
$$z+y=3 \, \text{and} \, z-y=1$$
thus $z=2, y=1$. If we permit negative integers, $z=-2, y=-1$ also work.

Now substituting,
$$x^2-4=12$$
so $x=\pm 4$.

And these values are consistent with the first equation:
$$4^2-1^2=15$$
so we are done.